# Sharepoint 2010, SPQuery Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, error, caml-query, sql-server

I have a SPQuery that getitems from a document libraries in different sites collections and display the result in listview, this query is generated from database table, everything works fine under 160 items, but when my database table >=  160 items, I have this error message : Value does not fall within the expected range
this is a part of my code

```
 private void BindReassessmentSelectorToControl()
    {
        private const string DROPDOWNLIBRARYFIELDS = "<FieldRef Name='{0}' /><FieldRef Name='{1}' /><FieldRef Name='{2}' /><FieldRef Name='{3}' /><FieldRef Name='{4}' /><FieldRef Name='{5}' /><FieldRef Name='{6}' />";
        private const string CAMLEQINPAGID = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='InpAgId'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq>";
        private const string CAMLEQAGENTID = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq>";            
        private const string CAMLWHERE = "<Where>{0}</Where>";
        string rootUrl = this.RootSiteUrl;
        string sortKey = this.LastSortKey;
        SortDirection sortDicection = this.LastSortDirection;
        string currentUrlPage = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString());
        using (DataTable reassessmentTable = Reassessment.GetReadOnlyReassement(ReassessmentStatus.RECEIVED, string.Empty, string.Empty, null))
        {
            List<string> conditionsFinancialStatement = new List<string>();
            List<string> conditionsAssessment = new List<string>();

            if (reassessmentTable != null && reassessmentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                reassessmentTable.Columns.Add(SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.OPENURL_FIELD, typeof(string));
                reassessmentTable.Columns.Add(SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SDCNAME_FIELD, typeof(string));
                reassessmentTable.Columns.Add(SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.COUNTRY_CODE_FIELD, typeof(string));
                reassessmentTable.Columns.Add(SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.FSFILEREF_FIELD, typeof(string));
                reassessmentTable.Columns.Add(SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.FSFILELEAFREF_FIELD, typeof(string));
                reassessmentTable.Columns.Add(SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.ASSFILEREF_FIELD, typeof(string));
                reassessmentTable.Columns.Add(SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.ASSFILELEAFREF_FIELD, typeof(string));
                reassessmentTable.Columns.Add(SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.INPASSDATE_FIELD, typeof(DateTime));
                reassessmentTable.Columns.Add(SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD, typeof(string));

                foreach (DataRow row in reassessmentTable.Rows)
                {
                    string agentId = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(row[ReassessmentsColumns.CODE]);
                    string reassessmentId = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(row[ReassessmentsColumns.REASSESSMENTID]);

                    row[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.OPENURL_FIELD] = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(currentWeb.Url, string.Format(OPENURL, reassessmentId, currentUrlPage));

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(agentId))
                    {
                        if (agentId.Length > 7)
                        {
                            agentId = agentId.Substring(0, 7);
                        }

                        string conditionFinancialStatement = string.Format(CAMLEQAGENTID, agentId);
                        string conditionAssessment = string.Format(CAMLEQINPAGID, agentId);

                        if (!conditionsFinancialStatement.Contains(conditionFinancialStatement))
                        {
                            conditionsFinancialStatement.Add(conditionFinancialStatement);
                        }

                        if (!conditionsAssessment.Contains(conditionAssessment))
                        {
                            conditionsAssessment.Add(conditionAssessment);
                        }
                    }
                }

                string whereFinancialStatement = string.Format(CAMLWHERE, this.BuildConditions(conditionsFinancialStatement));
                string whereAssessment = string.Format(CAMLWHERE, this.BuildConditions(conditionsAssessment));

                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    List<string> sdcNames = new List<string>();
                    string rootSiteUrl = this.RootSiteUrl;

                    using (SPSite rootSite = new SPSite(rootSiteUrl))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb rootWeb = rootSite.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            sdcNames = SummaryReportUtilities.GetSDCList(rootWeb);
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (string sdc in sdcNames)
                    {
                        Uri siteUri = new Uri(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(rootSiteUrl, SITESURL + sdc));
                        if (SPSite.Exists(siteUri))
                        {
                            using (SPSite sdcSite = new SPSite(siteUri.AbsoluteUri))
                            {
                                using (SPWeb sdcWeb = sdcSite.OpenWeb())
                                {
                                    SPList assessmentList = sdcWeb.GetList(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(sdcWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, DocumentLibrary.EXCELASSESSMENTLIBRARY));
                                    SPList dropdownList = sdcWeb.GetList(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(sdcWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, DocumentLibrary.DROPDOWN));
                                    SPQuery financialStatementQuery = new SPQuery();
                                    SPQuery assessmentQuery = new SPQuery();
                                    DataTable financialStatement = null;

                                    string webUrl = sdcWeb.Url;
                                    string webUrlServerRelative = sdcWeb.ServerRelativeUrl;

                                    financialStatementQuery.Query = whereFinancialStatement;
                                    financialStatementQuery.ViewFields = string.Format(DROPDOWNLIBRARYFIELDS, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.AGENTID_FIELD,
                                        SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SALESFORCECASENUMBER_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.COUNTRY_CODE_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD,
                                        SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.FILELEAFREF_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.FILEREF_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.CREATED_FIELD);


                                    try
                                    {
                                        if (dropdownList != null)
                                        {
                                           financialStatement = dropdownList.GetItems(financialStatementQuery).GetDataTable();

                                        }
                                       ...
```

it's the last line in the code : `financialStatement = dropdownList.GetItems(financialStatementQuery).GetDataTable();`
 that generate the error

```
SPQuery Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

when I debug financialStatementQuery 
this is the result :

```
<View><Query><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7727839</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2321605</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2304400</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2343423</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2364191</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2361004</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2357073</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2354730</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2342336</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2340844</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2319424</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2363126</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2362382</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2360470</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2358355</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2357902</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2354866</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2350622</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2350530</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2349745</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2346783</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2331151</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2302786</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7847708</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7847291</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9125539</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7847659</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6775733</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>5550033</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7823556</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7847269</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7847250</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7847238</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6832028</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7847200</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7847105</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2360632</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2721369</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6763071</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8210775</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2357202</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2346315</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2358521</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>4725815</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>4720007</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8270463</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8212083</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2301810</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9128671</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8147118</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8147069</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8147023</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2354343</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2341861</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2329891</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2308644</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9123781</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9510017</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6532171</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9147397</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2321762</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2047204</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2023457</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6471071</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9128034</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9127671</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7824575</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7823946</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>1330887</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8211932</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8202600</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8211011</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8477081</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9047121</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9147025</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>1747011</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8147655</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2360050</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7721764</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7720199</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>3730298</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>1330236</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2357633</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2352416</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7728515</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7720024</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>5921628</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2047397</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7828438</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9047127</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7827017</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7037001</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>3847337</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8358244</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7820644</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7825207</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7821019</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6421305</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2022571</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>1531428</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2361553</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7827801</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8780000</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8770002</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6921059</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7720338</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>1436703</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7845335</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>3530898</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8121144</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6920188</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6023058</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7825179</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7825123</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7828237</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2031518</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7820632</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6750441</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6151205</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7721345</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7720306</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7957040</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>5880017</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>1721057</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9247115</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7720995</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9127211</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6021099</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7832103</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7832046</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>3845014</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6992355</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9120451</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8121349</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8121274</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8121260</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8121215</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8121158</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8120248</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8021158</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7847401</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7729075</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7721891</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7721562</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7721204</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7721200</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>5721217</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>3628751</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>2131821</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>1431716</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8847006</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>8820018</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7822543</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6932037</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>9222878</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>7120699</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>6932042</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>5747103</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>3537091</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgentId'/><Value Type='Text'>5254546</Value></Eq></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='AgentId' /><FieldRef Name='SalesforceCaseNumber' /><FieldRef Name='CountryCode' /><FieldRef Name='ReviewType' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><FieldRef Name='Created' /></ViewFields><RowLimit Paged="TRUE">2147483647</RowLimit></View>
```

here I have 160 agentId, (for the same query but 159 agentId it works)
any idea ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Same problem with SP2010 and nested ORs, breaks when reaching 160+
>   nested items.

Check this: [What is the limit of nested OR's in a CAML Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530564/2144424)

Comment: from your link , they say : Solution is to break in multiple queries or change the way of querying, do you have an Idea how can I do it ? please ?

Comment: How many conditions do you have? The IN operator aparently has a limit of 500.

Comment: I will need max 450 conditions, so I need to use IN ? like in this example ? [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80210/caml-query-limitation-of-values-in-in-operator]

Comment: You can test with IN like this link. Or you have to look for another alternative as create filter on another field than the ID. But that depends on the logic of your application.