# CAML query to filter by more than one ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml

I have to send more than one ID to CAML query. But got struck with the or condition. How can we implement `or` condition for unknown number of ID's to be passed to the query.  I have done in for two ID's, now I need to do it for unknown number of ID's to be passed.

```
$('#tblCustomListData tbody').empty();
var array = $('#userid').val().split(",");

var camlQuery ="<Or>";
$.each(array,function(i){
   array[i] = array[i].trim();
   camlQuery = camlQuery + "<Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + array[i] + "</Value></Eq>";


});
camlQuery2 = camlQuery + "</Or>";
camlQuery2 = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where>"+ camlQuery2 +"</Where></Query></View>";

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('DocumentList');
var fileName = document.getElementsByName('userid')[0].value;

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml(camlQuery2);
allItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(allItems, 'Include(Title,DocumentTitle,Description0,DocID,OHRID,Modified,FileRef)');
```

How do we implement a query so that it work for any number of ID's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way to build a query for an unknown number of IDs is to use the `<In>` operator.  It's kind of like a multiple `Or` statement without having to nest all the `Or`s.

You could do something like:

```
var query = '<Where><In><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Values>';

array.forEach(function(id) {
    query += '<Value Type="Number">' + id + '</Value>';
});

query += '</Values></In></Where>';
```

Apparently the `In` operator has a limit of 500 items, so see [this other question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80210/caml-query-limitation-of-values-in-in-operator) about how to deal with a situation involving more than 500 items in an `In` query.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I build up a CAML statement with an unknown number of items. This is looping through a bunch of checkboxes to build an OR complex, but the basic structure is:
Build the outside of the query with any required ANDs.
Build the inside of the ORs - the first is just the Eq statement, the rest keep wrapping what you've got in s
Maybe you can translate some of that logic to what you need.

```
var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Launch_x0020_Date'/></OrderBy>";
    query += "<Where>"; 
    query += "<And><And>";
    query += "<Geq><FieldRef Name='Launch_x0020_Date'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + dateF + "</Value></Geq>";
    query += "<Neq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Choice' >00-Not Started</Value></Neq>";
    query += "</And>";
    query += buildCAMLSelect('Coder');
    query += "</And>";
    query += "</Where></Query>";
function buildCAMLSelect(fieldName) {
     var CAMLselect = '';
     var count = 0;
     $('.fmgSelectUser').each(function() {
         if($(this).is(':checked')) {
             if(count == 0){
             CAMLselect += "<Eq><FieldRef Name='" + fieldName + "' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Choice'>" + $(this).val()+ "</Value></Eq>";
             } else {
             CAMLselect = "<Or>" + CAMLselect + "<Eq><FieldRef Name='" + fieldName + "' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Choice'>" + $(this).val()+ "</Value></Eq></Or>";
             }
             count++;
         }

     });
     return CAMLselect;
 }
```