# Is there a limit of conditions count for oData query using $filter?

Tags: filter, odata, limitations

I have a long $filter query like `ID eq 1 or ID eq 2 or ID eq 33 or ID eq ...` and it works like a charm when we have up to 159 conditions joined by `or`.

But, when I add one more condition (started from 160) I have an error:

```
{"error": {
"code": "-2147024809, System.ArgumentException",
"message": {
  "lang": "en-US",
  "value": "Value does not fall within the expected range"
}}}
```

There is no problem with ID - condition can be like `ID eq 1 or ID eq 1 ...` - the issue occupied only with count of conditions.

In SP logs I see following:

```
    System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range, StackTrace:   
in Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()    
in Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollection.TryWriteAsOData(ServerStub serverStub, ODataWriter writer, RESTfulQuery query, ProxyContext proxyContext)    
in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.Write(Object value, Uri path, ODataWriter writer, RESTfulQuery query, ProxyContext proxyContext)    
in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process()    
in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest()    
in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream, IList1 pendingDisposableContainer)    
in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestService.ProcessRestQuery(Stream inputStream)    
in SyncInvokeProcessRestQuery(Object , Object[] , Object[] )    
in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    
in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)    
in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)    
in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)    
in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)    
in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)    
in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)    
in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)    
in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)    
in System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)    
in System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)    
in System.Runtime.InputQueue1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)    
in System.Runtime.InputQueue1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)    
in System.Runtime.InputQueue1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)    
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)    
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result)    
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result)    
in System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult result)    
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()    
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    
in System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)    
in System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()    
in System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()    
in System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)    
in System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)    
in System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)    
in System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped nativeOverlapped)    
in System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped nativeOverlapped)    
in System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

I read lots of documents about SP limitations bud didn't found any point about limit of conditions count.

Please help

UPDATE: URL length is not a problem - the same issue can be with much more longer url (like `VeryLongFiedName eq 123456 or VeryLongFiedName eq 123456 ...`). If I have 159 conditions like `VeryLongFiedName eq 123456` joined by `or` it works, but if there are 160 conditions it returns the error

Comment: Please go through this answer which is in similar context. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/194328/40602

Comment: There is no item about this limitation. URL length is not a problem - the same issue can be with much more longer url (like VeryLongFiedName eq 123456 or VeryLongFiedName eq 123456 ...). If I have 159 conditions like "VeryLongFiedName eq 123456" joined by "or" it works, but if 160 it returns error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you shouldn't query with so many conditions unless it is really necessary.
Following is a workaround which you can try.

If there are limitations in REST api multiple query conditions then you might think of using caml query `IN` operator in REST API.

```
function restCallwithCaml(listName, caml) {  
    /// get the site url  
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;  
    /// set request data  
    var data = { "query" :{"__metadata": { "type": "SP.CamlQuery" }, "ViewXml": caml}};  
    /// make an ajax call  
    $.ajax({  
       url: siteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('"+ listName +"')/GetItems",  
            method: "POST",  
            data: data,  
            headers: {  
               "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
               'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',  
               'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'  
            }  
            success: function (response) {  
            ///do your code  
            },  
            error: function (data) {  
            ///do your code  
           }  
    });  
}
```

You can define caml query like this to have more than 500 conditions.

```
<View>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
        <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Or>
                <In>
                    <FieldRef Name='ID' />
                    <Values>
                        <Value Type='Integer'>1</Value>
                        <Value Type='Integer'>2</Value>
                        <Value Type='Integer'>3</Value>
                        ...
                        <Value Type='Integer'>499</Value>
                    </Values>
                 </In>
                <In>
                    <FieldRef Name='ID' />
                    <Values>
                        <Value Type='Integer'>500</Value>
                        <Value Type='Integer'>501</Value>
                        <Value Type='Integer'>502</Value>
                        ...
                        <Value Type='Integer'>999</Value>
                    </Values>
                 </In>
            </Or>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

Reference: 
[SharePoint REST API - CAML Query](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-rest-api-caml-query)
[caml-query-limitation-of-values-in-in-operator](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80210/caml-query-limitation-of-values-in-in-operator)

Comment: maybe it depends on your server setup, but in my on-premise installation I had the limit set as 60, not 500.  Also, if you have more Value criteria than your limit, you'll need to start nesting <OR> tags