# How to get list items using multiple itemIDs

Tags: sharepoint-online, java

I have multiple itemIds, and I like to get the actual items using these itemids in just a single request, is that possible?
I know about getListItem() method but that would use only 1 itemid, hence will return only actual item itself.
I'm trying to avoid sending multiple requests per item id.

Comment: You can post your code what you have tried and we can convert that or provide a better solution then.

Comment: Did you try with below solution? Is that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a caml query with "IN" operator and pass it to the GetItems method

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee539544(v%3Doffice.15)

Operator has a limitation of 500 items but you can use a workaround with ORs:

[CAML query limitation of values in IN operator](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80210/caml-query-limitation-of-values-in-in-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can filter with multiple IDs. In your filter, query items like this:
ID eq 1 or ID eq 2 or ID eq 3...

But there is a limitation if you have too many IDs then it will not work.

---

*If the answer is helpful, please upvote and mark as accepted.*